# Injective map from set cartesian product of perfect squares to set of natural number

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am very interesting to figure out whether I am correct or not. Let $S$ denotes the collection of all perfect squares That is:
$$S:\{1,4,9,\cdot \cdot \cdot \}$$

I am interested to define an injective map from $$ S\times S \to \mathbb{N}$$.
My gauss is a following map $f$: $$f: S\times S \to \mathbb{N}$$ given by $$f(m,n)=3m+5n$$ I tried to prove it by simple definition as follows let: $$f(m_{1},n_{1})=f(m_{2},n_{2})$$
$$3m_{1} + 5n_{1} =3m_{2} + 5n_{2}$$
$$3(n_{1} - n_{2} )=5(m_{2} - m_{1} )$$.
I have a hard time proceeding further. I am in doubt whether my guess is correct at first place or not

Comment: There are simply defined  injections from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$.  Just restrict one of those.

Comment: @lulu, Actually I want an injection that map (m,n) such that the image does not involve the term "mn". I want a linear expression like am+nm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Can you find squares $n_1, n_2$ such that $n_1 - n_2 = 5$? Similarly, can you find squares $m_1, m_2$ such that $m_2 - m_1 = 3$?

---

**Edit:** Since this has been accepted, I assume that the OP was able to solve it.
For future readers: Easily checking the first few squares would show that that $1, 4$ and $9, 16$ have the property we want.